# Javascript error in internetexplorer webdriver in windows xp ie8

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, selenium

i have built an application using jdk 6 and i m using selenium 2.40. My program successfully runs in windows 7 and 8 but when i try to run it in Windows xp it throws the following exception.

```
    INFO: Retrying request
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: JavaScript error (WARNING: The server di
d not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 46 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DTA01-3F-ITD12', ip: '192.168.214.53', os.name: 'Windows XP'
, os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Session ID: 3b9bdf76-9fc2-42ed-9010-24c4748bbe53
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0
, ignoreZoomSetting=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=fals
e, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAler
tBehaviour=dismiss, version=8, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=
true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, requireWindowFocus=false, handlesAlerts=
true, initialBrowserUrl=https://www.himalremit.com/newpcregistration.php, ie.for
ceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserC
ommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.
java:193)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHa
ndler.java:145)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.ja
va:573)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDri
ver.java:482)
        at hbl.remit.com.Browser.main(Browser.java:108)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
```

This is my code

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
caps.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
caps.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
caps.setCapability("javascript.enabled", true);
caps.setCapability("initialBrowserUrl","https://www.gigle.com/preregistration.php");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);        driver.get("https://www.gigle.com/preregistration.php");                                            
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('caminfo').item(0).value = '"+regValue+"';");                 jse.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('reqip').item(0).value = '"+ipAddr+"';");                 jse.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('phyid').item(0).value = '"+PHYID+"';");
jse.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('hdid').item(0).value = '"+BIOSID+"';");

WebElement element  = driver.findElement(By.name("Submit"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Basically what it does is it submits above values in a form and submit the form.

The preregistration.php is this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Himal Remit</title>
<script language = "JavaScript">
function setCount(target){
if(target == 0) document.f1.action="https://www.gigle.com/registration.php";
document.f1.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="f1">
<input type="hidden" name="caminfo" value="" id="caminfo">
<input type="hidden" name="reqip" value="" id="reqip">
<input type="hidden" name="phyid" value="" id="phyid"> 
<input type="hidden" name="hdid" value="" id="hdid">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" hidefocus="true" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; border: none; padding: 0px;" onClick="setCount(0)">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help.
THanks

Comment: Well you appear to be using Selenium just to execute JavaScript, so why are you using Selenium at all in that case? You aren't using Selenium for it's intended purpose here.

Comment: i have built an desktop application(exe) which whenever double clicked,opens up a browser in this case ie and submits some value in the opened webpage form

Comment: So why doesn't Selenium work normally? Why does `.findElement().Click()` not work?

Comment: because all the fields are hidden inside the form